# Chrome page crashes "Aw, Snap" after loading too many elements in a page. Increasing the cache would fix the issue?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, crash, cache, browser-cache

I am scrolling through a lot of elements in a web page. To be more specific, I am scrolling through a lot of Facebook profiles and I've noticed that after a while the page crashes saying "Aw, Snap". Increasing the browser default cache size would fix the issue? If so, how can I do that for Google Chrome?

Edit: I am on a MacBook Pro M2.

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit operating system with sufficient memory?

Comment: Yes, I am. MacBook Pro M2.

Comment: This means you are most likely running into data structure limits in the Blink engine. There is nothing you can do. You should instead encourage website operators to stop using endless scrolling and/or implement virtualization.